# What happens when I click 'Don't Click'?

Tags: candy-box

[image]

I used the 'Developper's Computer' to add a tab. Should I click it?

Comment: It doesn’t always say *Don’t Click*; the tab text is random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I could tell clicking the generated tab(s) didn't do anything at all. It didn't even open the the tab or anything.
And obviously not clicking the tab(s) doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Clicking the new tabs freezes your game.

Comment: Actually, simply creating the tab seems to make it impossible to click any of the other tabs either (so make sure you saved before entering the developper’s computer).